# Python game - players take turns to subtract from a number

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the scenario:

Ask the user for a number which must be between 20 and 30. The user and the computer take it in turns to subtract 1, 2 or 3 from the current value. The last player to subtract a value loses.

Here's what I have so far

```
import random
while True:
    count = int(input("Enter a number between 20 and 30"))
    if count < 20 or count > 30:
        print("That number is not in range")
    else:
        print("\nLet's play")
        print("\nSubtract 1, 2, or 3 from", count)
# Player moves
def playermove():
    while True:
        number = int(input("\nWhat number would you like to subtract"))
        if number > 1 and number <4:
            print("\nyou subtracted", number, "there is", count-number, "left")
            print("\nMy turn!")
            break
        else:
            print("\nplease enter 1,2 or 3")

def computermove():
        computernum = random.randint(1,3)
        print("\nI subtracted", computernum, "there is", count-computernum, "left")
        print("\nMake your move")
```

Comment: You're still missing some critical pieces to make this work. My first advice is make choosing the initial value a function. Then you need to call those functions to actually do something. What you've written so far is just an infinite loop.

Comment: I have been playing around at calling the functions, none of it worked so I removed it. I originally had a break in the first loop, don't know what happened to it....Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0):

Get the initial count from the user something like this:

```
def get_count():
    count = 0
    while count < 20 or count > 30:
        count = int(input("Enter a number between 20 and 30"))
        if count < 20 or count > 30:
            print("That number is not in range")
        else:
            return count

count = get_count()
```

Next, start playing the game.